# Use angularjs module in directive.js instead of controller.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am doing custom validation for form with ng-messages so I need to parse some strings. Hence, i have imported ng-string to utilise its function. Unfortunately, i can only use it in controller.js but not in directive.js. 
Things i tried:

1. importing string whenever i can in directive.js

   ```
           .directive('ngCustomdir', function(){
       return {
           restrict: 'A',
           require:'ngModel',
           link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel, string){
               ngModel.$validators.customdir= function(modelValue){
                   console.log("checking");
                   return false;
               };
               ngModel.$validators.validemail=function(modelValue, string){
                   console.log("string:" + string('  ToTrim ').trim().s);

               }
           }
       }
   });
   ```

2.return a controller to do the parsing(I put a dummy controller that prints hello)

```
    .directive('ngCustomdir', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require:'ngModel',
            link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel, string){
                ngModel.$validators.customdir= function(modelValue){
                    console.log("checking");
                    return false;
                };
                ngModel.$validators.validemail=function(modelValue, string){
                    //console.log("string:" + string('  ToTrim ').trim().s);
                    return{ 
                        controller: 'parseEmailCtrl'
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .controller('parseEmailCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicHistory, $stateParams) {
      console.log('hello');
    })
```

What should i do? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can't you just inject string at the top, i.e. .directive('ngCustomdir', function(string){ ?

Answer (score 0):

Inject in directive itself then use it anywhere you need within whole directive

```
 .directive('ngCustomdir', function(string){
```

the `link` has predetermined arguments and is not injectable

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `app.directive('ngCustomdir', function(){` where `app` is defined on `index.html` page as `ng-app="app"`.
Then in `app.js` file define `var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic',etc.]);` then you can use `app.directive('ngCustomdir', function(){`.
Regards